# Add 'Watermark' to images with php

Tags: php, image, watermark

I have a website where users may upload images...

I need to add my logo (watermark) to the images once they are uploaded.

How can I do so?

And it is important that the watermark is in a corner where it will be visible, for example I have seen websites which generates a watermark on the fly, and puts the mark wherever the background of the main image is "the same color" so the watermark sticks out if you know what I mean.

Anybody have a good tutorial or article about this?
Or know of any function in php which I would need to find the position of the watermark?

Comment: you can use this solution :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829674/adding-watermark-to-image-in-php/60740632#60740632

Answer (score 59, accepted):

A [good example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php) in the PHP manual:

```
// Load the stamp and the photo to apply the watermark to
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('stamp.png');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('photo.jpeg');

// Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

// Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo 
// width to calculate positioning of the stamp. 
imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

// Output and free memory
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: Even tho this was a few years back here is the source. http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php

Comment: How would I call that on the client side?  Im used to simply making an img tag with an address.

Comment: you can use watermarkjs. https://www.patrick-wied.at/static/watermarkjs/

Comment: You can learn watermark images using php here. http://programmerblog.net/watermark-images-using-php/

Comment: Great! But is there a way of doing this on webp image files?

Answer (score 24):

use this function 
the type of watermark image must be "png"

```
 function watermark_image($target, $wtrmrk_file, $newcopy) {
    $watermark = imagecreatefrompng($wtrmrk_file);
    imagealphablending($watermark, false);
    imagesavealpha($watermark, true);
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($target);
    $img_w = imagesx($img);
    $img_h = imagesy($img);
    $wtrmrk_w = imagesx($watermark);
    $wtrmrk_h = imagesy($watermark);
    $dst_x = ($img_w / 2) - ($wtrmrk_w / 2); // For centering the watermark on any image
    $dst_y = ($img_h / 2) - ($wtrmrk_h / 2); // For centering the watermark on any image
    imagecopy($img, $watermark, $dst_x, $dst_y, 0, 0, $wtrmrk_w, $wtrmrk_h);
    imagejpeg($img, $newcopy, 100);
    imagedestroy($img);
    imagedestroy($watermark);
}

watermark_image('image_name.jpg','watermark.png', 'new_image_name.jpg');
```

Answer (score 12):

**Good Example of watermark image and positioned at the center**

```
<?php
// Load the stamp and the photo to apply the watermark to
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('stampimg.png');
$im = imagecreatefrompng('mainimage.png');

// Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

$imgx = imagesx($im);
$imgy = imagesy($im);
$centerX=round($imgx/2);
$centerY=round($imgy/2);

// Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo 
// width to calculate positioning of the stamp. 
imagecopy($im, $stamp, $centerX, $centerY, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

// Output and free memory
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a much better solution which add a watermark dinamically through .htaccess, you can find the tutorial here:

[Add watermark to images through htaccess](http://www.reviewsforjoomla.com/forum/index.php?topic=15067.0)

After uploading the custom .htaccess file, the watermark.php scrypt, and your watermark.png image, all the images in the folder and its subfolders will show the watermark, however, you will still keep the original file in the server.

Hope that helps someone the same that it helped to me.

Comment: Good solution as it's easy but it's a requiring more server resources as it treats image over and over (on each display) in place of doing it once and for all. it can make a big difference on websites with big traffic.

Comment: this is not a good solution, every time that user reload page, this script will be load.. more server resources...

Comment: It is kind of a temporal solution. The good thing is that you can implement it without touching the module code. However, more effort will be needed in sites with big traffic

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using an image manipulation library such as [GD](http://www.libgd.org/Main_Page) or [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). Here is a tutorial that explains a way to do it using GD:

http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/watermark-images-php

Comment: Hi I have also issue, it gives me resource id and I can't able to upload it, means move_uploaded_file does not works please help me to resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) works well for that. I've done it before. The whole business is a bit of a pain, though. Especially if you want fancy blending modes and the like.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Load the stamp and the photo to apply the watermark to

$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('stamp.png');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('photo.jpg');
$save_watermark_photo_address = 'watermark_photo.jpg';

// Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image

$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

// Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo 
// width to calculate positioning of the stamp. 

imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

// Output and free memory
// header('Content-type: image/png');

imagejpeg($im, $save_watermark_photo_address, 80); 
imagedestroy($im);
```