# add watermark to the image and save it as image not php file

Tags: php

i have PHP uploading script,i need to add watermark on the image after the user upload it .

i tried many ways but all in the end give you PHP path to preview the image

i need to do the same in this link http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php but save this into real image to have image path like this"my_new_image_with_watermark.jpg"
not just file.php

The code actually is:

```
<?php
// Load the stamp and the photo to apply the watermark to
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('stamp.png');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('photo.jpeg');

// Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

// Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo 
// width to calculate positioning of the stamp. 
imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

// Output and free memory
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

thanks

Comment: https://github.com/Sybio/ImageWorkshop

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829674/adding-watermark-to-image-in-php/60740632#60740632

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
// Output and free memory
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Write:

```
$filename = '/foo/bar.png';
imagepng($im, $filename);
imagedestroy($im);
```