# add watermark image to uploaded image

Tags: php, image, upload, watermark

I'm using this code to add a png image as a watermark to uploaded image but the result is not an image and don't want to use header() i want the code to continue to execute other php queries without navigation to another page to display the image. The image get uploaded but without the watermark and the header() doesn't post any image just a small grey square

```
$path = "../large/";
$num = substr(md5(mt_rand(1,9999999999)),0,9);    
$new_name = $path.$num.".jpg";
$image = $num.".jpg";
move_uploaded_file($img_tmpname,$new_name);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($new_name);
$logoImage = imagecreatefrompng("images/watermark.png");
imagealphablending($logoImage, true);
$imageWidth=imagesx($image);
$imageHeight=imagesy($image); 
$logoWidth=imagesx($logoImage);
$logoHeight=imagesy($logoImage);

imagecopy(
  // destination
  $image,
  // source
  $logoImage,
  // destination x and y
  $imageWidth-$logoWidth, $imageHeight-$logoHeight,
  // source x and y
  0, 0,
  // width and height of the area of the source to copy
  $logoWidth, $logoHeight);

// Set type of image and send the output
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagePng($image);

// Release memory
imageDestroy($image);
imageDestroy($imageLogo);
```

Comment: `imagePng` should be `imagepng` and `imageDestroy` should be `imagedestroy`

Comment: the path `images/watermark.png` ~ firstly does the file exist in that location and secondly have you tried using the full path to that image?

Comment: Yes I did but the same problem

Comment: Use this for the coolest example.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829674/adding-watermark-to-image-in-php/60740632#60740632

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this using the code below and this worked ok. Obviously I have used paths relevant to my test system but hopefully it should help.

One of the most important and often forgotten things when uploading and dealing with uploaded files is the `enctype` of the form - so I included my test form as an example.

If you want to save the image as well as display it with the watermark use the imagepng function twice, once with a filename and the other without.

```
<form method='post' action='/test/so/wtrmarkimg.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <h1>Image uploader - Watermark</h1>
    <input type='file' name='image' />
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>

<?php

    #$path = "../large/";

    $path='c:/temp/';/* output path for images generated */
    $watermarksrc=realpath( 'c:/wwwroot/images/watermark.png' );    

    if( isset( $_FILES['image'] ) ){

        $img_tmpname=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];


        $num = substr( md5( mt_rand( 1,9999999999 ) ),0,9);    
        $new_name = $path.$num.".jpg";
        $image = $num.".jpg";

        if( move_uploaded_file( $img_tmpname, $new_name ) ){

            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg( $new_name );
            $logoImage = imagecreatefrompng( $watermarksrc );
            imagealphablending( $logoImage, true );

            $imageWidth=imagesx($image);
            $imageHeight=imagesy($image); 
            $logoWidth=imagesx($logoImage);
            $logoHeight=imagesy($logoImage);

            imagecopy(
              $image,
              $logoImage,
              $imageWidth-$logoWidth, $imageHeight-$logoHeight,
              0, 0,
              $logoWidth, $logoHeight );

            // Set type of image and send the output
            header("Content-type: image/png");
            imagepng( $image );/*display image with watermark */
            @imagepng( $image, $new_name );/* save image with watermark */

            // Release memory
            imagedestroy( $image );
            imagedestroy( $imageLogo );
        }
    } else {
        echo "ERROR";
        print_r($_FILES);   
    }
?>
```

Comment: No errors and no posted image. The original image was just moved to the path.

Comment: can you show what and how you have altered your code?

Comment: Adjusted a little and now works fine thanks a lot 
$path='../large/';/* output path for images generated */
 $watermarksrc=realpath( 'images/watermark.png' );