# Add watermark on valums file uploader

Tags: php

Hi i using this uploader script on my website http://fineuploader.com/

```
<?php

 /**
 * Handle file uploads via XMLHttpRequest
 */
 class qqUploadedFileXhr {
/**
 * Save the file to the specified path
 * @return boolean TRUE on success
 */
function save($path) {    
    $input = fopen("php://input", "r");
    $temp = tmpfile();
    $realSize = stream_copy_to_stream($input, $temp);
    fclose($input);

    if ($realSize != $this->getSize()){            
        return false;
    }

    $target = fopen($path, "w");        
    fseek($temp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    stream_copy_to_stream($temp, $target);
    fclose($target);

    return true;
}
function getName() {
    return $_GET['qqfile'];
}
function getSize() {
    if (isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_LENGTH"])){
        return (int)$_SERVER["CONTENT_LENGTH"];            
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Getting content length is not supported.');
    }      
}   
}

   /**
   * Handle file uploads via regular form post (uses the $_FILES array)
    */
      class qqUploadedFileForm {  
/**
 * Save the file to the specified path
 * @return boolean TRUE on success
 */
function save($path) {
    if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['qqfile']['tmp_name'], $path)){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
function getName() {
    return $_FILES['qqfile']['name'];
}
function getSize() {
    return $_FILES['qqfile']['size'];
}
 }

 class qqFileUploader {
private $allowedExtensions = array();
private $sizeLimit = 10485760;
private $file;

function __construct(array $allowedExtensions = array(), $sizeLimit = 10485760){        
    $allowedExtensions = array_map("strtolower", $allowedExtensions);

    $this->allowedExtensions = $allowedExtensions;        
    $this->sizeLimit = $sizeLimit;

    $this->checkServerSettings();       

    if (isset($_GET['qqfile'])) {
        $this->file = new qqUploadedFileXhr();
    } elseif (isset($_FILES['qqfile'])) {
        $this->file = new qqUploadedFileForm();
    } else {
        $this->file = false; 
    }
}

private function checkServerSettings(){        
    $postSize = $this->toBytes(ini_get('post_max_size'));
    $uploadSize = $this->toBytes(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));        

    if ($postSize < $this->sizeLimit || $uploadSize < $this->sizeLimit){
        $size = max(1, $this->sizeLimit / 1024 / 1024) . 'M';             
        die("{'error':'increase post_max_size and upload_max_filesize to $size'}");    
    }        
}

private function toBytes($str){
    $val = trim($str);
    $last = strtolower($str[strlen($str)-1]);
    switch($last) {
        case 'g': $val *= 1024;
        case 'm': $val *= 1024;
        case 'k': $val *= 1024;        
    }
    return $val;
}

/**
 * Returns array('success'=>true) or array('error'=>'error message')
 */
function handleUpload($uploadDirectory, $replaceOldFile = FALSE){
    if (!is_writable($uploadDirectory)){
        return array('error' => "Server error. Upload directory isn't writable.");
    }

    if (!$this->file){
        return array('error' => 'No files were uploaded.');
    }

    $size = $this->file->getSize();

    if ($size == 0) {
        return array('error' => 'File is empty');
    }

    if ($size > $this->sizeLimit) {
        return array('error' => 'File is too large');
    }

    $pathinfo = pathinfo($this->file->getName());
    $filename = $pathinfo['filename'];  
    $filename = date("Ymdhis").md5($pathinfo['filename']);
    $ext = $pathinfo['extension'];

    if($this->allowedExtensions && !in_array(strtolower($ext), $this->allowedExtensions)){
        $these = implode(', ', $this->allowedExtensions);
        return array('error' => 'File has an invalid extension, it should be one of '. $these . '.');
    }

    if(!$replaceOldFile){
        /// don't overwrite previous files that were uploaded
        while (file_exists($uploadDirectory . $filename . '.' . $ext)) {
            $filename .= rand(10, 99);
        }
    }

    if ($this->file->save($uploadDirectory . $filename . '.' . $ext)){
        return array('success'=>true, 'filename'=>$filename . '.' . $ext, 'filethumb'=>'/img/Garotas/'.$filename . '.' . $ext);
    } else {
        return array('error'=> 'Could not save uploaded file.' .
            'The upload was cancelled, or server error encountered');
    }

}    
 }

    // list of valid extensions, ex. array("jpeg", "xml", "bmp")
   $allowedExtensions = array();
    // max file size in bytes
      $sizeLimit = 10 * 1024 * 1024;

   $uploader = new qqFileUploader($allowedExtensions, $sizeLimit);
    $result = $uploader->handleUpload('../../img/Garotas/');
    // to pass data through iframe you will need to encode all html tags
       echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($result), ENT_NOQUOTES);
```

so i want to add a watermark on images before save the image to destination folder, can anyone give me a help on this, ive try using a couple scripts but for sure i have no idea how implement this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add Watermark to images with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235152/add-watermark-to-images-with-php).    Also, [this tutorial](http://www.phpjabbers.com/put-watermark-on-images-using-php-php20.html) would help

Comment: hi @HashemQolami i tried using this tutorial, but i m new with this and i dont know on what part of the upload handler i need to manipulate the image to add the watermark before save.

Answer (score 0):

Look, `save` method in `qqUploadedFileForm` class, moves uploaded file to `$path`,
So, if I decide to explain easily, after `if` statement ends, you can get the uploaded file from `$path` and add your watermark using these tutorials:

- [Text-Watermark](http://www.phpjabbers.com/put-watermark-on-images-using-php-php20.html)
- [Image-Watermark](http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples.merged-watermark.php)

**NOTE:**
Take a look to `imagepng()` or `imagejpeg()` syntax to find out how to **replace** prepared image.
You cal Also replace `watermark-image` to `source-image` by using   `copy('/address/to/watermark-image', '/address/to/source-image');`

You might also want to consider: [watermark-all-your-uploaded-images](http://dolcepixel.com/how-to-watermark-all-your-uploaded-images/)  tutorial.