# PHP watermark image

Tags: php, image-processing, watermark

I am trying to watermark images on upload.

I have a multi upload script in place which works fine, see below:

```
           $gallery=$_GET["gallery"];
                    $album=$_GET["album"];
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    $errors= array();
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
        if($file_size > 2097152){
            $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }       
        $query="INSERT into commerce_images (`USER_ID`,`FILE_NAME`,`FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`, `added_by`, `gallery_id`, `sub_gallery_id`) 
        VALUES('$user','$file_name','$file_size','$file_type', '$Fname $Sname', '$gallery', '$album'); ";
        $desired_dir="uploads";
        if(empty($errors)==true){
            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
            }else{                                  // rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
                 rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
            }
         mysql_query($query);           
        }else{
                print_r($errors);
        }
    }
    if(empty($error)){
?>

<script>location.assign("commerce-images.php?state=new");</script>
                                        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Is it possible to watermark all images uploaded using my script?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Maybe something like [this](http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php) ? Also - you shouldn't use the mysql* functions anymore as they are deprecated. Switch to `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: @uri2x - Thanks for your comment. I have looked at that yes, but as a newbie I'm not sure how that fits into my script?

Comment: if you want to show more of your query info, I can convert it to PDO for you while you wait for the smart PHP people

Comment: @Drew - I have edited my question with the whole script.

Comment: how about obfuscated connection info and the `$query` assembly. Cool thx

Comment: @drew Not sure what you mean?

Comment: makes two of us. working on it

Comment: @Drew haha, thanks Drew :)

Comment: @Shaun what kind of watermark are you trying to add? Text or an other picture in a transparent layer?

Comment: @kayess - Image in a transparent layer

Comment: @Drew - How's it going?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add 'Watermark' to images with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235152/add-watermark-to-images-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While OP's question wasnt crystal clear on the exact method of watermarking, im showing here text and image watermarking capabilities using the GD library.

---

**Adding text as watermark (using TTF font):** [Gist](https://gist.github.com/kayesshu/c9f1b5fd30bdcf072d7d)

```
function add_text_watermark($kep,$Text,$WatermarkNeeded = 1) {
    list($img_type, $Image) = getImage($kep);

$sx = imagesx($Image) ;
$sy = imagesy($Image) ;

if ($WatermarkNeeded)
    { 
    /* Set the font */
    $Font="_arial.ttf";
    $FontColor = ImageColorAllocate ($Image,204,204,204) ;
    $FontShadow = ImageColorAllocate ($Image,100,100,100) ;
    $Rotation = 0 ;
    /* Make a copy image */
    $OriginalImage = ImageCreateTrueColor($sx,$sy) ;
    ImageCopy ($OriginalImage,$Image,0,0,0,0,$sx,$sy) ;

    /* Iterate to get the size up */
    $FontSize=1 ;
    do
        {
        $FontSize *= 1.1 ;
        $Box = @ImageTTFBBox($FontSize,0,$Font,$Text);
        $TextWidth = abs($Box[4] - $Box[0]) ;
        $TextHeight = abs($Box[5] - $Box[1]) ;
        }
    while ($TextWidth < $sx*0.9 && $FontSize < 30) ;
    /*  Awkward maths to get the origin of the text in the right place */
    $x = $sx/2 - cos(deg2rad($Rotation))*$TextWidth/2 ;
    $y = $sy/2 + sin(deg2rad($Rotation))*$TextWidth/2 + cos(deg2rad($Rotation))*$TextHeight/2 ;
    /* Make shadow text first followed by solid text */

    ImageTTFText ($Image,$FontSize,$Rotation,$x+1,$y+1,$FontShadow,$Font,$Text);
    ImageTTFText ($Image,$FontSize,$Rotation,$x,$y,$FontColor,$Font,$Text);

    /* merge original image into version with text to show image through text */
    ImageCopyMerge ($Image,$OriginalImage,0,0,0,0,$sx,$sy,50) ;
    imagejpeg($Image, $kep, 100);
    }
}

function getImage($res) {
    $img = "";
    $type = "";

    if (intval(@imagesx($res)) > 0) {
        $img = $res;
    } else {
        $imginfo = getimagesize($res);

        switch($imginfo[2]) { // Determine type
            case 1:
                $type = "GIF";
                if (function_exists("imagecreatefromgif")) {
                    $img = imagecreatefromgif($res);
                } else {
                    die("Unsupported image type: $type");
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                $type = "JPG";
                if (function_exists("imagecreatefromjpeg")) {
                    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($res);
                } else {
                    die("Unsupported image type: $type");
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                $type = "PNG";
                if (function_exists("imagecreatefrompng")) {
                    $img = imagecreatefrompng($res);
                } else {
                    die("Unsupported image type: $type");
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    return array($type, $img);
}
```

**EDIT:** make sure the ttf font file you are trying to add as watermark text are in sight of the path!

---

**Adding Image as watermark:** [Gist](https://gist.github.com/kayesshu/6a5c5fc329e459ed96a3)

```php
function generate_watermarked_image($originalFileContents, $originalWidth, $originalHeight, $paddingFromBottomRight = 0, $watermarkFileLocation = 'logo.png') {
$watermarkImage = imagecreatefrompng($watermarkFileLocation);
$watermarkWidth = imagesx($watermarkImage);  
$watermarkHeight = imagesy($watermarkImage);

$originalImage = imagecreatefromstring($originalFileContents);

$destX = $originalWidth - $watermarkWidth - $paddingFromBottomRight;  
$destY = $originalHeight - $watermarkHeight - $paddingFromBottomRight;

// creating a cut resource
$cut = imagecreatetruecolor($watermarkWidth, $watermarkHeight);

// copying that section of the background to the cut
imagecopy($cut, $originalImage, 0, 0, $destX, $destY, $watermarkWidth, $watermarkHeight);

// placing the watermark now
imagecopy($cut, $watermarkImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $watermarkWidth, $watermarkHeight);

// merging both of the images
imagecopymerge($originalImage, $cut, $destX, $destY, 0, 0, $watermarkWidth, $watermarkHeight, 100);

return $originalImage;
}
```

You can call it as:

```
$Image = "$desired_dir/".$file_name;

imagejpeg(generate_watermarked_image(file_get_contents($Image), imagesx($Image), imagesy($Image), 10), $Image."-watermarked.jpg", 100);
```

**EDIT:** make sure the logo.png or whatever file you are trying to add as watermark are in sight of the path!

Comment: Thanks where in my code does this go /  what does it replace?

Comment: @Shaun IMHO right at the place where you are storing the file at its final place. Eg. after your file system operations copy/move/rename.

Comment: ermm, new to this and have no idea? sorry!?

Comment: @Shaun before or after where you have the line with `mysql_query($query);`. Which i meant as the file is stored on its final place at.

Comment: @kayees sorry to be a pest, but could you show me the new code (mine above) edited with yours?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89466/discussion-between-shaun-and-kayess).

Answer (score 2):

Off topic, but requested, hopefully it helps someone get from `mysql_*` to `PDO` out there. PDO Manual Page for [bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php), to point you someplace at least.

### Schema

```
create table commerce_images 
(   `id` int auto_increment primary key,
    `USER_ID` int not null,
    `FILE_NAME` varchar(123) not null,
    `FILE_SIZE` int not null,
    `FILE_TYPE` int not null, 
    `added_by` varchar(100), 
    `gallery_id` int not null, 
    `sub_gallery_id` int not null
);
```

### php

```
<?php
    // Begin Vault (this is in a vault, not actually hard-coded)
    $host="localhost";
    $username="GuySmiley";
    $password="anchovies_¿^?fish╔&®";
    $dbname="so_gibberish";
    // End Vault

    try {

        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $username, $password);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $user=456;
        $file_name="/path";
        $file_size=29832;
        $file_type=3;
        $Fname="Kim";
        $Sname="Billings";
        $gallery=35;
        $album=9;

        $FullName="$Fname $Sname";

        // prepared statement with named placeholders for sanity of not using index values of placeholders
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT into commerce_images (`USER_ID`,`FILE_NAME`,`FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`, `added_by`, `gallery_id`, `sub_gallery_id`) 
        VALUES(:user,:file_name,:file_size,:file_type,:FullName,:gallery,:album)");
        $stmt->bindParam(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_INT);   // correct this datatype
        $stmt->bindParam(':file_name', $file_name, PDO::PARAM_STR,123); // size it
        $stmt->bindParam(':file_size', $file_size, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':file_type', $file_type, PDO::PARAM_INT); // correct this datatype
        $stmt->bindParam(':FullName', $FullName, PDO::PARAM_STR,123);   // size it
        $stmt->bindParam(':gallery', $gallery, PDO::PARAM_INT); // correct this datatype
        $stmt->bindParam(':album', $album, PDO::PARAM_INT); // correct this datatype
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt = null;
        // PDO closes connection at end of script

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'PDO Exception: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }
?>
```

### Results

```
select * from commerce_images;
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------+------------+----------------+
| id | USER_ID | FILE_NAME | FILE_SIZE | FILE_TYPE | added_by     | gallery_id | sub_gallery_id |
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------+------------+----------------+
|  1 |     456 | /path     |     29832 |         3 | Kim Billings |         35 |              9 |
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------+------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, does this also do the watermar?

Comment: No, this code is responsible for one thing only (as it should be), handling the persistence to database.

Comment: no sir, as seen in earlier comments, as I was saying I would show PDO while the smart PHP people helped with watermarks.