# Adding Watermark to php doesnt work seems empty

Tags: php, watermark, php-gd

I want to use watermark image  with php. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235152/add-watermark-to-images-with-php) is my reference page

```
function imagecreatefromfile($image_path) 
{
list($width, $height, $image_type) = getimagesize($image_path);
switch ($image_type)
{
 case IMAGETYPE_GIF: return imagecreatefromgif($image_path); break;
 case IMAGETYPE_JPEG: return imagecreatefromjpeg($image_path); break;
 case IMAGETYPE_PNG: return imagecreatefrompng($image_path); break;
 default: return ''; break;
 }
}
$image = imagecreatefromfile($_GET['image']);
if (!$image) die('Unable to open image');
$watermark = imagecreatefromfile('uploads/files/water.png');
if (!$image) die('Unable to open watermark');
$watermark_pos_x = imagesx($image) - imagesx($watermark) - 8;
$watermark_pos_y = imagesy($image) - imagesy($watermark) - 10;
imagecopy($image, $watermark,  $watermark_pos_x, $watermark_pos_y, 0, 0,
imagesx($watermark), imagesy($watermark));
header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
imagejpeg($image, '', 100); 
imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($watermark);`
```

but my page seems empty ,

This is my test page

http://www.alanyaticaretrehberi.com/watermark.php?image=uploads/firmaresim/750/address-cikcilli-3jpg.jpeg

this worked in other servers but not worked in my server.

This is my phpinfo page..

http://www.alanyaticaretrehberi.com/php.php

I guess some setting missed in my php settings but i dont know what it is. May be it is about gd library or something else, can you give some advices for this issue.

Comment: Have you tried giving your files an absolute path? What happens if you just run `imagecreatefromfile`?

Comment: i tried it with just imagecreatefromfile with absolute path but it Causes http 500 error.