# How to set video icon permanently on image

Tags: php, html, css

I want to set  permanently video icon on image, but i can't. When i do that, two image are showing: 1. video icon 2. my image, but not adjust 1 and 2 at once one image.
 **More Clearly:** I wants to share a photo with video icon. I have image without video logo. I wants to add video logo on image using code. I don't wants to set logo using photoshop.

HTML:

```
<div class="video">  
    <img style="height:200px" src="http://i.imgur.com/GMjqTR7.jpg"/>
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.video {
    position: relative;
}
.video a {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background: url(/images/play-btn.png);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 75px;
    left: 150px;
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Please Help Me. Thanks.
[JSFiddle - Live](https://jsfiddle.net/6daLwyua/)

Comment: please clarify the question.

Comment: thanks for reply... I wants to share a photo with video icon. I have image without video logo. I wants to add video logo on image using code. I don't wants to set logo using photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done on the client or server side. Based on the fact that your example only contains front-end code, I'll assume you want to this on the front-end.

Take a look at watermak js
http://brianium.github.io/watermarkjs/

For a server-side example, see this answer
[Add 'Watermark' to images with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235152/add-watermark-to-images-with-php)

Comment: I wants to direct set icon on video, after download image video icon show.