# Add Watermark to every image [!resourcespace!]

Tags: php, image, resources, space, watermark

https://www.resourcespace.com/

The solution provided by resource space is adding watermark to "preview" images only.

Is there a tweak, patch that can add water mark to each and every image - including original image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add 'Watermark' to images with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235152/add-watermark-to-images-with-php)

Comment: Thanks @Hackerman - but here we are using a whole solution already developed http://www.resourcespace.com/.

Comment: Then if you have that solution, and you own a license, then the best thing to do is to contact customer-support center and ask if there is a way to accomplish what you want, and how.

Comment: @Hackerman, Thanks for the answer, It's and open source just like wordpress, I have already asked over there, but it would be great if the question is here also, so anyone get and answer to that.

Comment: i guess not, because if you add watermark to original images then you could accidentally add another one over the previous and so on...

Comment: I can't see the code in a public repo whatsoever, and I don't want to download the full code in order to check for an unidentified functionality....but what should I do if I were you, I'll check the code of the method that add the watermark to preview images only, and create another method based on that one, that could provide the functionality that I want, in this case add a watermark to every image inside a folder.