# php image upload with adding text

Tags: php, upload, imagejpeg

I created an uploader for myself, now what I am trying is adding text on it too. I already created it outside the uploader but I just can't combine them two, already tried multiple sequences but failed :( need help here's the code.!

Here is the upload code.

```
$file_name = $_FILES[attach][name];
$caption=$_POST["caption"];
$uploaddir = "../photos";
$up_path=$uploaddir."/".$file_name;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attach']['tmp_name'], $up_path);
```

Here's the text on img code:

```
$get_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('name.jpg');
$white = imagecolorallocate($get_image, 255, 255, 255);
$txt = "Hello World";
$font = "arial.ttf"; 
imagettftext($get_image, 24, 0, 5, 24, $white, $font, $txt);
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($get_image, "name.jpg", 100);
imagedestroy($get_image);
```

Comment: Please always show what you tried. _“Here's the text on img code:”_ - that uses `name.jpg` in two places - so which parts could possibly need replacing …? You _know_ where you just moved the uploaded file to, `$up_path`. (Whether it _needs_ moving could be discussed here, you could probably just work with `$_FILES['attach']['tmp_name']` as the input file instead.)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve watermarking using image libraries.
You can find examples here.

[Add 'Watermark' to images with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235152/add-watermark-to-images-with-php)

An alternative way is to use FFMPEG Library which can be executed through php exec() method. See the link below.

[How to add transparent watermark in center of a video with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918907/how-to-add-transparent-watermark-in-center-of-a-video-with-ffmpeg)

Comment: i just saw the code, but looks like it can add pictures only, i am trying to add the caption of the photos,

Comment: You can create a bitmap of the caption text with alpha channel and add it as a picture/bitmap